# ClickOnce does not produce one single WPF app file

Tags: wpf, single-file, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I published my WPF project following these steps

1. Choose ClickOnce
2. Choose output location
3. Define version, etc.
4. Choose Self-contained, produce single file

[image]

However, I still see Application Files in the output folder and if I delete it, the app doesn't work. I watched some tutorial on Youtube and see that if I publish the app this way, I don't need other files, as well as the users don't have to install .NET. But it doesn't seem to be the case.
[image]

I even use command line (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli) but the result was the same. When running the app on another pc, it still asks me to install .NET. Did I setup it wrong or the tutorial I saw was a success because they were simple projects and don't have many dependencies?

Comment: *[...] or the tutorial I saw was a success because they were simple projects and don't have many dependencies?* - what keeps you away from testing it with a simple project?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you cannot package a ClickOnce app into a single executable `.exe` file out of the box.

You need to choose between ClickOnce or single-file deployments - it's one or the other but not both. Or package the ClickOnce app into an archive or something yourself and then extract the archive before installning the app.

Comment: Single-file WPF apps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74777974/create-self-contained-single-exe-file-from-c-sharp-wpf-application/74817606#74817606