# How to include .NET 8.0 Runtime in a Windows Application Packaging Project

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-8.0, self-contained, windows-application-packaging

I have a solution with a .NET 8.0 WPF application and a .NET 8.0 Windows Application Packaging Project. When i try to install it on a machine that does not have .NET 8.0 Runtime installed, the installation works but the application wont start.

So is there a way I can somehow include it in the package?

I tried  adding "<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>" and

```
<Target Name="_RemoveFrameworkReferences" BeforeTargets="_ConvertItems;_CalculateInputsForGenerateCurrentProjectAppxManifest">
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkSdkReference Remove="@(FrameworkSdkReference)" Condition="$([System.String]::Copy('%(FrameworkSdkReference.SDKName)').StartsWith('Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

in both the Packaging Project and WPF application but it didn't seem to do anything

Comment: Does this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74777974/create-self-contained-single-exe-file-from-c-sharp-wpf-application ? Also you should consider creating an installer that installs all necessary dependency before you install your application on machine.

Comment: If you deploy the app as self-container, the .NET 8 runtime will be included.

Comment: Hi @mm8 , isnt that what  "<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>" should be doing, or do i need some other flag?